# ExtJS 4 Carousel widget

Tags: extjs, widget, extjs4, carousel

Carousel is part of Sencha Touch, however:

I'm looking for an example of a carousel/scroller type widget that allows me to horizontally slide through a collection of items that I can act on. Does ExtJS provide such a widget, or the components to build one?

Comment: did you get the carousel working? I'm trying to implement a carousel for ExtJS too and although I made it work, I still have an error that makes it extremely annoying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slide horizontally through a [`Ext.carousel.Carousel`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-cfg-direction) when you set the `direction` config to 'horizontal' (default).

---

**Edit:**
You can copy the `Carousel.js` from the sencha touch build and create your own Carousel in ExtJs4.

Rename and refactor some of the configurations and you are good to go.

Refactor example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.carousel.Carousel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
```

must be

```
extend: 'Ext.container.Container' ,
```

[[Source]](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?145146-ExtJS-4-and-Ext-Core-Carousel)
I hope this works for you.. I'm pretty sure it will but if it doesnt let me know.

Comment: Ext.carousel.Carousel is the class of Sencha Touch not Ext 4 - I am looking for solution with very similar functionality for Ext.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question.. let me fix that.